# how to display value of input in DIV object in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, addeventlistener

F.e I have div which id is someDiv and input text which id is someInput - and how to do that value of input object will display in DIV in real time? If i type letter "a" in input, it should automatically display in DIV.
Which function should I use?
I'm the real begginer in jQuery.

I find this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#someInput').keyup(function() {
        $('#someDiv').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: use jquery `keyup` for this

Comment: Why did you tag PHP ? Look on Google for Javascript inputs. We won't write you your code.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: If you just give some html I'm sure you will get a example of how to do it

Answer (score 3):

Use `input` event

```js
$(function() {
  $('#someInput').on("input", function() {
    $('#someDiv').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="someInput">
<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="realTimeInput" type="text"/>
<div id="someDiv">
</div>


<script>
$("#realTimeInput").on('change',function(){
    $("#someDiv").text($("#realTimeInput").text());
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this code , when you keyup theb this value will show in content div so you can also input event like keypress, change etc

```js
 $('#someInput').keyup(function () {
        $('#yourinput').show();
        //  var dev = $(this).val();
        $('#yourinput').html($(this).val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Enter Text :<input id="someInput" type="text"/>
<div id="yourinput" style="display: none;border: 1px solid #ccc;margin-top:10px;">
</div>
```

for more information

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla Javascript Alternative:**

Use the `addEventListener()` method to invoke a callback function when a specified *event type* occurs (e.g: `keydown`) on an `EventTarget`.

**ES5:**

```
var INPUT_EL  = document.getElementById('UI_input'),
    OUTPUT_EL = document.getElementById('UI_output');

function updateText() {
  OUTPUT_EL.innerHTML = INPUT_EL.value;
}

INPUT_EL.addEventListener('keydown', updateText);
```

```js
var INPUT_EL  = document.getElementById('UI_input'),
    OUTPUT_EL = document.getElementById('UI_output');

function updateText() {
  OUTPUT_EL.innerHTML = INPUT_EL.value;
}

INPUT_EL.addEventListener('keydown', updateText);
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="UI_input" value="test value">
  <div id="UI_output">this is sample</div>
</body>
```

**ES6:**

```
const INPUT_EL  = document.getElementById('UI_input');
const OUTPUT_EL = document.getElementById('UI_output');

let updateText = () => OUTPUT_EL.innerHTML = INPUT_EL.value;

INPUT_EL.addEventListener('keydown', updateText);
```

```js
const INPUT_EL  = document.getElementById('UI_input');
const OUTPUT_EL = document.getElementById('UI_output');

let updateText = () => OUTPUT_EL.innerHTML = INPUT_EL.value;

INPUT_EL.addEventListener('keydown', updateText);
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="UI_input" value="test value">
  <div id="UI_output">this is sample</div>
</body>
```